# Generate array of all html entities

Tags: c, code-generation, html-entities

I have a program where i need to escape all html entities in a string. I have array of entity=>substitute pairs and function that does search and replace. It would be very hard to write all possible entities to array by hand. How could i generate array of all possible entities with their substitutes?

Here is the function i have in use currently:

```
static char *replacehtmlentities(char *str) {
    int i;
    char *tmp = NULL;
    char *tmp2 = str;

    struct entity {
        char *entity;
        char *substitute;
    } entities[] = {
        { "&nbsp;", " " },
        { "&excl;", "!" },
        { "&quest;", "?" },
        { "&amp;", "&" },
        { "&num;", "#" },
        { "&quot;", "\"" },
        { "&apos;", "'" },
        { "&#39;", "'" },
        { NULL, NULL },
    };

    for (i = 0; entities[i].entity; i++) {
        tmp = replace_str2(tmp2, entities[i].entity, entities[i].substitute);
        if (i)
            free(tmp2);
        tmp2 = tmp;
    }

    return tmp2;
}
```

Comment: homework is hard, isn't it? :)

Comment: Do it, test it, document it and put it on the web. **Earn** reputation.

Comment: OT: `replace_html_entities()` is easier to read.

Comment: akira and alk: those aren't very constructive comments.

Comment: You also have to decide what codepages to support. Should your code only support e.g. UTF-8, or also various others?

Comment: You could look at e.g. PHP's https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard , `html.h`, `html.c`, `html_tables.h`, and the directory `html_tables` as well as `tests`. Not to say you should do it that way, but you might find some of it useful. I.e. the *resources* section at top of `html.c`

Comment: Why use a list? Everything *starting* with an ampersand `&` is potentially an entity. After that, it comes down to *validating*. 1. There are only so many allowed characters in an entity (irrespective of the used codepage! There *are* no higher encoded UTF8 characters that may appear inside it!). 2. Properly it should end with a semicolon `;`. Note that browsers may be relaxed about that last requirement. After validating you could test against a list, but IIRC 'invalid' named entities are silently ignored -- again, browser and version dependent. Also, the support for names differs hugely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote program "genentities" that reads html entities online from http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/entities.json and outputs C header with structure containing all entities with substitutes.

Here is the final program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE  (1024 * 1024)  /* 1024 KB */

char *url = "http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/entities.json";

void eprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct write_result {
    char *data;
    int pos;
};

static size_t write_response(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {
    struct write_result *result = (struct write_result *)stream;

    if(result->pos + size * nmemb >= BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
        eprintf("error: too small buffer\n");

    memcpy(result->data + result->pos, ptr, size * nmemb);
    result->pos += size * nmemb;

    return size * nmemb;
}

static char *request(const char *url) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode status;
    char *data;
    long code;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    data = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (!curl || !data)
        return NULL;

    struct write_result write_result = {
        .data = data,
        .pos = 0
    };

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &write_result);

    status = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (status != 0)
        eprintf("error: unable to request data from %s:\n"
                "%s\n", url, curl_easy_strerror(status));

    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &code);
    if(code != 200)
        eprintf("error: server responded with code %ld\n", code);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    data[write_result.pos] = '\0';

    return data;
}

static char *replace_str2(const char *str, const char *old, const char *new) {
    char *ret, *r;
    const char *p, *q;
    size_t oldlen = strlen(old);
    size_t count, retlen, newlen = strlen(new);
    int samesize = (oldlen == newlen);
    if (!samesize) {
        for (count = 0, p = str; (q = strstr(p, old)) != NULL; p = q + oldlen)
            count++;
        /* This is undefined if p - str > PTRDIFF_MAX */
        retlen = p - str + strlen(p) + count * (newlen - oldlen);
    } else
        retlen = strlen(str);
    if ((ret = malloc(retlen + 1)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    r = ret, p = str;
    while (1) {
        /* If the old and new strings are different lengths - in other
         * * words we have already iterated through with strstr above,
         * * and thus we know how many times we need to call it - then we
         * * can avoid the final (potentially lengthy) call to strstr,
         * * which we already know is going to return NULL, by
         * * decrementing and checking count.
         * */
        if (!samesize && !count--)
            break;
        /* Otherwise i.e. when the old and new strings are the same
         * * length, and we don't know how many times to call strstr,
         * * we must check for a NULL return here (we check it in any
         * * event, to avoid further conditions, and because there's
         * * no harm done with the check even when the old and new
         * * strings are different lengths).
         * */
        if ((q = strstr(p, old)) == NULL)
            break;
        /* This is undefined if q - p > PTRDIFF_MAX */
        ptrdiff_t l = q - p;
        memcpy(r, p, l);
        r += l;
        memcpy(r, new, newlen);
        r += newlen;
        p = q + oldlen;
    }
    strcpy(r, p);
    return ret;
}

char *escapeformatspecifiers(const char *src) {
    int i;
    char *tmp = NULL;
    char *tmp2 = src;

    struct formatspecifiers {
        char *specifier;
        char *substitute;
    } fspecs[] = {
        { "\\", "\\\\" },
        { "\"", "\\\"" },
        { "\n", "\\n" },
        { NULL, NULL },
    };

    for (i = 0; fspecs[i].specifier; i++) {
        tmp = replace_str2(tmp2, fspecs[i].specifier, fspecs[i].substitute);
        if (i)
            free(tmp2);
        tmp2 = tmp;
    }

    return tmp2;
}

int main(void) {
    char *text;
    const char *key;
    size_t index;
    json_t *root;
    json_t *value;
    json_t *arrvalue;
    json_t *characters, *codepoints;
    json_error_t error;
    char *chartmp;

    text = request(url);
    if(!text)
        return 1;

    root = json_loads(text, 0, &error);
    free(text);

    if (!root)
        eprintf("error: on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
    if (!json_is_object(root))
        eprintf("error: root is not an object\n");

    puts("#ifndef HTMLENTITIES_H");
    puts("#define HTMLENTITIES_H\n");
    puts("struct entity {");
    puts("\tchar *entity;");
    puts("\tchar *substitute;");
    puts("} entities[] = {");
    json_object_foreach(root, key, value) {
        characters = json_object_get(value, "characters");
        codepoints = json_object_get(value, "codepoints");
        if(!json_is_array(codepoints))
            puts("not an array");
        chartmp = escapeformatspecifiers(json_string_value(characters));
        printf("\t{ \"%s\", \"%s\" },\n", key, chartmp);
        json_array_foreach(codepoints, index, arrvalue) {
            printf("\t{ \"&#%.0f;\", \"%s\" },\n", json_number_value(arrvalue), chartmp);
        }
        free(chartmp);
    }
    puts("\t{ NULL, NULL },");
    puts("};\n");
    puts("#endif");

    json_decref(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
this method of writing a struct:

struct entity 
{     
    char *entity;
    char *substitute;
} entities[] = {
    { "&nbsp;", " " },
    { "&excl;", "!" },
    { "&quest;", "?" },
    { "&amp;", "&" },
    { "&num;", "#" },
    { "&quot;", "\"" },
    { "&apos;", "'" },
    { "&#39;", "'" },
    { NULL, NULL },
};

is depreciated (and many debuggers will not display the individual fields).

this is the correct/preferred method:

struct entity_t 
{
    char *entity;
    char *substitute;
};

struct entity_t entities[] = 
{
    { "&nbsp;", " " },
    { "&excl;", "!" },
    { "&quest;", "?" },
    { "&amp;", "&" },
    { "&num;", "#" },
    { "&quot;", "\"" },
    { "&apos;", "'" },
    { "&#39;", "'" },
    { NULL, NULL },
};

where I used 'entity_t' to differentiate the struct declaration from
the field within the struct

also, if not compling 'strict ansi', the final ',' is not needed
```